What type of circuit is this? Common gate, common source and so on?
I am trying to classify this transistor configuration according to CS, CG, CD, but have been unable to do so... Any tips or ideas in how to classify it?

The image above is from my professor's presentation.  He asked students to do some simulations using this circuit.
Another example using a similar configuration can be found below.  It is from Question 11 in "Electronics Question Bank for Qualifying Examination for Doctoral Courses in the Department of Electrical Engineering" (in Chinese, from Taiwan).


Where is the input signal?

@Carl so these types of classification only makes sense in small signal analysis? If DC, or in biasing it is not possible to classify it at all?

@eggrobot_91 You may be overthinking this. Don't worry about DC/AC analysis or small signal parameters right now. Sure, solving the gain can tell you the type of amplifier but to solve for gain, you need an input voltage to amplify.

The PN junction into substrate suggests merely a diode with "gate" shield for some reason -- or is this a common transistor type? (I've seen this symbol abused often enough, it's worth asking to specify type and pin connection.)

I answered your question and showed some simulations.  Since Vt is -ve,Use Vgs = Vds to compute Id for Vgs, then compute Vo referenced to ground. But Vgs(th) has a 2:1 range so how will you know Vt unless you know how to measure it as I indicated at 1/1000 of the rated current.  As such, I feel the Mods were wrong to delete it for the reason given.  The symbol problems were answered too.

Short answer
Your circuit represents the so-called "diode-connected PMOS transistor". It constitutes a voltage-type negative feedback circuit that maintains a relatively constant voltage (voltage stabilizer). It is mostly used as an input part of current mirrors.
The transistor is connected in a common source configuration. Its input (gate-source) voltage is the output (drain-source) voltage.
For completeness, below I have presented the possible variants with PMOS and NMOS transistors. For each, I have attached a voltage plot as a function of varying resistance Rd (DC sweep simulation).
Diode-connected PMOS transistor
Floating output
The output voltage is across the source-drain region of the transistor. However, it is referenced to Vss, not to ground. This is inconvenient in most cases.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Grounded output
Therefore, we can instead use its complement to the supply voltage (i.e., the voltage drop across the resistor). A known disadvantage is that if Vss is not stable and varies, the output voltage will follow these changes.

simulate this circuit

Diode-connected NMOS transistor
Grounded output
There is no such a problem with the NMOS implementation.

simulate this circuit

Floating output
If we ever need a floating load (which is pretty unlikely), we could use the voltage drop across the resistor Rd as our output.

simulate this circuit

What does "diode-connected" mean?
@kaosad raised a great point in their response. Here is my take on it.
Clearly, the term "diode" is used to draw a parallel between this transistor circuit and a diode. The issue is that there are multiple diode-like characteristics. A diode can act as a one-way valve for current, regulate voltage, or perform non-linear conversion between current and voltage. Here, we are talking about the latter two.
As @kaosad pointed out, the IV characteristic of the BJT implementation indeed closely matches the diode IV characteristic, but the NMOS implementation does not quite match. Let's see why.
BJT implementation
Base-emitter diode: The BJT base-emitter junction behaves like a diode. We can verify this by plotting its characteristic. Let's do this by (carefully) varying the voltage around 0.7 V and measuring the current. As you can see, in this arrangement, the collector is disconnected.

simulate this circuit

Diode-connected BJT: Now let's connect the collector to the base. In this way, the collector-emitter part of the transistor (that, according to @Edin Fifić behaves like a voltage-controlled "resistor") is connected in parallel to the base-emitter junction, and acts like a powerful shunt buffer.

simulate this circuit
The shape of its IV curve is a replika of the base-emitter IV curve.

BJT current mirror: With this connection, we have made a transistor behave like a diode. If we cascade such an "inverted" transistor with a normal one, we get a current-to-current converter known as a current mirror. The interesting thing is that the characteristics of the two individual transistors are non-linear...

simulate this circuit
... but the overall characteristic of the BJT current mirror is linear.


NMOS implementation
Gate-source "non-diode": Unlike the BJT implementation which copies the true diode characteristic, there is no diode in the input circuit here. As you can see, there is no current; there is only voltage.

simulate this circuit

Diode-connected NMOS transistor: The transfer characteristic of an NMOS transistor is also nonlinear, but it is not a diode characteristic.

simulate this circuit
Ultimately, due to voltage-type negative feedback, this configuration has a diode-like characteristic with the main property of stabilizing the voltage.

NMOS current mirror: As above, if we cascade an "inverted" NMOS transistor with a normal one, we get a current mirror. The characteristics of the two transistors are non-linear, and they are not diode characteristics but that does not matter...

simulate this circuit
... since the overall characteristic of the NMOS current mirror is linear.



See also my answer to a related question.

To me this is the one correct answer. Clear and to the point. Canonical. And while I'm at it, I'd like to recommend the book "Designing Analog Chips" by the late Hans Camenzind, as an excellent cookbook having many examples of practical circuits, with explanations.

@frr, Thanks a lot! It's not often that someone says something nice to me here. I struggle to read books because I get lost in thought. Years ago, I used to take my favorite book (usually "The Art of Electronics") with me on vacation to get my brain working again. Cheers!

I have to agree with @frr here, your answer is clear and to the point. Personally, I was stuck on the classic analog amplifier in my mind for some reason, and thus my answer above. User D.A.S. was very persistent that it IS an "amplifier" of a sort and that it DOES have a common electrode, and I felt that he might be right but couldn't really get it until I saw your answer.  You made your point right from the start clearly and concisely, and I got it right away. I also struggle to keep reading as my mind wanders all the time. "The A. of E." is also my favorite leisure read (got one too)!

@Edin Fifić, Thank you! You remind me of the kind of human connection I thought was a thing of the past. It is wonderful and so exciting...

I don't understand your "floating output" and "grounded output" headings. You place a volt meter, which is in ideal circumstances just an open circuit. So you measure once the voltage over the transistor and once over the resistor. You haven't changed anything in the circuit. And the result is trivial, because the 5 V have to divide over two elements, so the sum is 5 V.

@Arsenal, Exactly. I have played out the possible experiments to stimulate thinking. "Floating" means it is referenced to Vss (it will "float" if Vss changes).

TL;DR, but it looks great as usual. You outdid me for details on uses. :)  Although I still think of Vgs(th) as the input-controlled output to Vo, thus CS, since one has to choose it, but it doesn't matter to me as much as understanding why and what to expect in the real world of high volume production with tolerances on Vt and Id effects on Vo.

@D.A.S., (Tony) Like you, I have become a bit addicted to simulations, but I break them down into many separate steps, accompanied by local explanations (CircuitLab turned out to be very convenient for such a presentation). It really turns out to be a bit long "comics", but the ideas are revealed well. Cheers, Cyril :-)

@D.A.S., It is interesting that for many years I visualized currents and voltages with colored loops and bars, and even animated them using Flash Animator... but now these moving currents in Falstad bother me. Maybe because now I am breaking down a simulation into multiple static frames.

Options> Show Current ( uncheck ), colors are selectable or choose Show Power for white or amplify power slider  for shade of Red

I prefer floating stacked plots with stats and labels added but it takes practice to do fast  https://i.sstatic.net/26GzVgJM.png. More could be done to save Falstad settings with the open source.

Neither, because you have to be able to have an input voltage between either two electrodes, and then the output voltage between another electrode and one that is used already, which would make that the common electrode.
Your circuit has two electrodes shorted, making an input or an output voltage impossible or zero.
Plus your drain and source are upside down and the source indicates wrong polarity.
This could only work as a diode limited to the maximum gate-source voltage.
Whoever drew this circuit, had no idea what they were doing.
EDIT: I have to correct myself on my last sentence above: my assumption at a glance was based on the title of the question (this is certainly not an amplifier, and it's certainly not one of those "common electrode" arrangements") and the possibility of the circuit in question being a current source.
In either case, the schematic symbol is wrong, and that's what made me automatically assume ignorance of the designer.
However, there was also ignorance on my part: this type of circuit is used to provide a relatively constant voltage across the drain and source electrodes, which I have learned quickly afterwards.
"Jumping the gun" typically leads to life's lessons in humility and realization of one's own ignorance.
EDIT #2: One more lesson in ignorance and humility: the user "Circuit Fantasist" has given the best answer here and I have to agree with him.
I had no knowledge of the "official" name and all details about this circuit, but I did quickly realize its fairly stable voltage capability and vaguely remembered seeing it in the internal schematics of some integrated circuits.
In summary, although this is not an "amplifier" in the classic sense (increasing the input voltage or current), it is a "common electrode" arrangement.
Since I can't describe it any better than he has done at the beginning of his answer, I will have to quote his words exactly:
(Quoting answer from user "Circuit Fantasist" below)

Your circuit represents the so-called "diode-connected PMOS
transistor". It constitutes a voltage-type negative feedback circuit
that maintains a relatively constant voltage (voltage stabilizer). It
is mostly used as an input part of current mirrors.
The transistor is connected in a common source configuration. Its
input (gate-source) voltage is the output (drain-source) voltage.

This is the beauty of various minds meeting, each contributing to the overall picture, knowledge and understanding.

Do you not recognize the circuit for measuring Vgs(th) with a large R on a PFET?  Why +2 votes. Are you sure about what you are saying? I had to correct mine.

This is the correct answer. Commonality is only meaningful when there are more than two connections: for N=2 it's a one-port with neither input nor output, just a relationship of voltage and current.  (A one-port can still be used as an amplifier, tunnel diodes for example; but there's nothing to be "common" to.)  When we have N=3, we define one connection as common, and the remaining two are ports with respect to that common. It is then meaningful to have CD/CG/CS terminology when a FET is connected to such a fixture.

@TimWilliams  I respect your opinion but How do you define Vt?  as a 1 port or 2 with a condition on 2 ports and the 3rd being common.

@D.A.S. There is a Vo in the question; what is Vt? Power supplies are not defined as signals, and ground is defined as reference, leaving one signal port (but it would be helpful if OP specified port(s)). You can separate the circuit into a two-port having a certain relationship between the ports, but the circuit overall is at best a one-port.

Power Supply is certainly a signal for Vs just as Gnd is a 0V voltage sink for Vo and a global reference but you use V+ -Vg to obtain Vgs=Vds with R as I proposed.
Both 1.6V and 0V are references to Id and both are short circuit AC common ports but necessary to compare Id with R. Also @Edin correctly found an identical circuit without the improper short-hand "not" on the input. which I may snip here  https://i.sstatic.net/Z4tlRHdm.png if the link moderators allow as it uses Edin's link in comments.  FWIW Tim

@TimWilliams  What is Vt? Vt is referenced from V+ while Vo = Id* R is referenced to  Gnd = 0V, as always.  You cannot analyze this circuit as a 1 port, but you can use it as such with R. Does this make sense now?

"Whoever drew this circuit, had no idea what they were doing." I beg to differ. This self-biasing configuration has a number of useful applications.

I agree @kaosad but those who disagree include 8 votes and Mr. Williams, Mr. Fifić, Mr Hearth, Mr. toolic, and Mr. spike. Others who understand include, you and Carl but no one else. I wonder what eggbot_71's Prof would say and the Mods are afraid to admit they erred.

@D.A.S. I never said the circuit is useless, and I would appreciate you not misconstrue my intent.

Mr. Williams Pls. read the 2nd sentence. What comments have you made to correctly identify this circuit and how to identify a common pin and solve Vo. I think your opinions contradict mine and are incorrect. Do you need more justification?  I am not doing what you suggest. Sorry if you misunderstood this rather simple problem.

I don't care if the circuit is called CS or not, but what should it be called where is used is more relevant and how does it behave? Yet you did not think to support or analyze my answer and instead call it a 1-port at best. Why make this so hard to resolve?

@D.A.S. I agree with you on many points, and I have included an edit at the bottom of my question. I just don't agree on it being an amplifier as it does not increase the amplitude either of a voltage or a current applied. I will also edit the question to include a reference to very much the same circuit, and would appreciate voting to reopen it.

@D.A.S. You misunderstand the question: it is not how to analyze the circuit, or what it does, or for what purpose you might use it; this appears to be the angle you are approaching it from, and this has created a lot of unnecessary friction. Rather, the question asks, "which type of amplifier [CS/CD/CG] is it?" -- this is a category question, not a function question. But the circuit cannot fit into that category, so the correct answer is -- well, the meta-answer is that it's a "bad question" (i.e., a mistaken premise), but a written answer here can indicate such to the OP.

@TimWilliams  A "common" configuration does not need to be an amplifier. The friction was caused by those who denigrated the diagram's author, misdiagnosed the part, and made assumptions about which pin is a "port" which is ambiguous to the general purpose of this "common" configuration. I merely tried to correct those and believe others misunderstood the question more than I, given by the lack of context. For those with experience to recognize this configuration as I did, I agree and I disagree with it being called a 1 port as you did. I think that is a false premise.

The only input is the internal Vt with it's 2:1 typical range that exists for almost all MOSFET due to mfg tolerances, even those that operate under 1.2V. The only output is Vo but Vgs=Vds use different references. i.e. 1.2V (to Vgs) and 0V(to Vo) I also analyzed this CS circuit to compute AND simulate as suggested in the question. One cannot simulate properly without understanding this CS configuration and appreciated the bonus info I added, to simulate it with various Vt's and R values without understanding how 1.2V affects a Pch differently from its complement Nch

If this were the complement Nch then input Vgs=Output Vds  the subscript letter "common" to both voltages is "s". However, using a Pch does not negate the "common source" configuration.

I posted my answer and hope that it clears things up.


Whoever drew this circuit, had no idea what they were doing.

or - Or - OR - - -
they knew how to design a constant-current source.
Constant Current FET Circuit
To be clear, there is an electronic component you can purchase called a constant-current diode.  Internally, the part is a FET just like the schematic in the question (without the resistor).
Here is a Vishay app note on the topic.  Page 1 applies to your circuit.
Vishay App Note
Piling on:
Electronic Design

Why did you think it was a JFET ?

Your reference sites use JFETs, although similar but different. Yet the resistor is on the wrong location to act as Constant current, so it does not match the circuit. Rather it matches the circuit for Vgs=Vds at low current, often used as a load for high gain common source NFETs.  So I wonder why it has +2 votes

@D.A.S. It doesn't need to be a JFET, it can be a depletion-mode MOSFET as well. And the resistor is optional, if you get the desired current without it.

The circuit appears to me as Vgs=Vds which is not constant current, rather constant Vgs(th) at << 1% rated current where a large R-value as shown is mandatory or more common as a load for a cascode Nch CS amp with high gain. But it not the correct symbol for either a depletion mode FET or  JFET

This question, and answer, illustrates the problem with the shorthand symbol used: it is contrary to long-standing notation, and so is (at best) meaningless by itself, and only meaningful in reference to other things (e.g., a mashup of MOSFET and BJT symbols). What's worse, I've seen it both drawn and wired incorrectly, in documents by manufacturers themselves -- it's rife for misuse and misunderstanding, and everyone is just worse off overall than if we had kept using the traditional symbol.

I'm not sure if I should downvote this answer for making a clear error -- or upvote for its satirical value!  Perhaps I will upvote anyway, as either way, it's bringing attention to this all-too-ignored subject (even if it might not be the answer OP desired or expected). :-)

At a quick glance I thought the same but then I realized it’s not connected correctly for that. In a CCS connected FET the gate connects to the source. In this circuit it appears to be connected to the drain.

I am familiar with JFETs, not MOSFETs, in this manner as constant current sources when their GATE and SOURCE are shorted together (GATE and DRAIN are shorted in the question). Also, the symbol is for a MOSFET without a body diode, and a MOSFET needs more than the 1.2V indicated in the schematic to work at all. Finally, the question was which amplifier configuration this is, and this is not an amplifier at all. So, the questioner got WRONG SYMBOL, WRONG SCHEMATICS and WRONG QUESTION. Though I maybe should have added some more explanation, my answer is still that basically someone had no clue.

@TimWilliams Yes it is satirical, there are symbolic mistakes, but the configuration is not the same as an CC source which you can purchase but has nothing to do with this question and the answer should be a CS but no mention here does not deserve any +1. I was the one pointing out the symbol error FWIW

@Heath It doesn't have to be and doesn't even look like JFET and the resistor is not optional as it would burn up the FET unless Vt was close to 1.2V which has no predictable or practical use (due to Vt tolerances) except measuring Vt with a large R value

What's This Stuff All About JFETS?  It is not a CC source nor a JFET.  Delete it or add to the GPT noise.  Bob Pease is rolling his eyes at this.

I should call it the Common Source using an Enhanced Pch MOSFET, but the variety of different symbols used in textbooks sometimes confuses me.
Not a J-FET nor an Nch FET or NFET.
 and no bulk?

The Wiki site 3 shows similar symbols as MOSFET enh. (no bulk).
I added outlines to the commercial MOSFETs, both Enh. and Dep.
The author used a mix of the two std. no-bulk MOSFET symbols (citation required) It shows an inverted circle on input and an arrow on the source going in rather than a modern symbol for the arrow out.
This should be the Pch Polarity for testing Vgs(th) when Vgs= Vds with both shared for input gate and output drain use the common source pin as a reference, thus "Common Source".

The reason gate input makes sense is to measure the Vgs threshold for output drain current, Id where each supplier chooses a near-off state current threshold to measure Vgs(th). Normally they would use a regulated current sink to measure the Vgs(th) in the above circuit, but choosing R in the above circuit has very low sensitivity since (Vgs-Vt)^2=0 if you chose the value to verify in the range you expect.

Vgs(th) is also known as (aka) Vt in textbooks

Vgs(th) typically has wide mfg. tolerance range of Vgs(th) for max/min = 2 typically  (e.g. 2 to 4V)

The rated current seems to always be between 1k and 10k times this threshold Id current for the RdsOn @ Id (rated).

In other words Id rated/threshold = 1k to 10k
e.g. if V+ = 1.2V and device under test, DUT has Vgs(th) max = 600 mV (nom) at 1mA you can choose R = 600 Ohms to 1K verify the actual Vgs(th) with minimal error.  minimal considering the 2:1 range of all parts @ Tj=25'C



Using a Pch FET with V+ = 1.2V this might be a suitable choice.
example https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/rochester-electronics-llc/PHK04P02T-518/15643222
Falstad web-sim
Other info:
But aside from conflicting symbol standards, the circuit is high impedance constant voltage near Vgs(th) if R is much (>=1000x) greater than RdsOn.   If R is small then  \$I_{ds} = \beta * (V_{gs} - \dfrac{V_{gs(th)})^2}{2})\$ and \$V_s=I_{ds}R+|V_{gs(th)}|\$ showing absolute value of Vds for Pch which is -ve.

From Edin's link in comments:
"Electronics Question Bank for Qualifying Examination for Doctoral Courses in the Department of Electrical Engineering" (in Chinese, from Taiwan), and the link to the PDF is https://ee.ccu.edu.tw/var/file/97/1097/img/1526/267104269.pdf

I honestly don't get all this commotion about this question. Isn't the circuit just a diode connected P-channel MOSFET transistor? Maybe the original question was to determine what $V_o$ was, given a $V_t$ and a $W/L$ ratio along with $\mu_pC_{ox}$. From that, you can readily determine the drain current because the device is in saturation, and then you can find $V_o$ via Ohm's law. What do you think?

I agree but the others have ignored the issues I explained in my answer but their's were with tangential opinions and mine has been ignored that it is a 3 pin device with 1 common pin, in this case, the source, with Vg=Vd used to compute Vo with extra info, which I explained how to measure since W/L is not given in datasheets unless chosen by simulation.  The tangent was caused by the wrong shorthand symbol from someone's Prof. I think the issue should be corrected by re-opening the question and review my answer and supplement if necessary.

I have upvoted your answer for the sole reason that you give a nice overview of the various schematic symbols. Also I'd like to point out the historical mess in the direction/polarity of the arrow in the "source" electrode. Reading historical schematics, especially if a tricky question is to be suspected (a school exam) I'd point out that based on context, we can guess what polarity the arrow actually means in the case at hand, to make some sense at all.

I'm happy to see the positive influences of other great answers.

This circuit cannot be classified as an amplifier, because there is no input signal. Recall that the voltage gain of an amplifier is \$A_v = \frac{V_o}{V_\text{in}}\$.
As shown in the circuit, the gate of the PMOS is connected to its drain. This implies that \$V_\text{gs}=V_\text{ds} \$. This is called a "diode connection". Recall that for a PMOS device to be in saturation we require that \$V_\text{ds}\leq V_\text{gs}-V_t \: \: \: \text{and} \: \: \: V_\text{gs}\leq V_t\$.
For PMOS devices \$V_t < 0 \$ so you know for certain that the device is in saturation. This information can be used to obtain an expression for the drain current \$I_d\$ (using the Shichman-Hodges model), from which the \$L\$ parameter can be determined.

For additional reference, here are a couple of other questions/answers which cover diode-connected MOSFETs.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/684234/why-does-current-mirror-need-a-diode-connected-configuration  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/725274/diode-connected-load

The circuit has an input signal and this is its output signal :-)

Answer
Before diving into the answer, let's differentiate the concepts with the help of the following picture.


Figure (a): This is a structure called a Diode-Connected PMOS (refer to section (A) below for more details).

Figure (b): Here, we have a biasing configuration involving power nodes and resistor(s), known as Drain-Feedback Biasing.

Figure (c): This shows an amplifier circuit that includes input and output signals, known as a Common-Source Amplifier with Drain-Feedback Biasing.


To answer the OP's question, the circuit provided is too incomplete to determine if it's a Common-Source (CS), Common-Gate (CG), or Common-Drain (CD) amplifier. If you had provided a diagram similar to figure (c), indicating the points where the input signal is applied and the output signal is taken, it would have clearly shown the amplifier mode.
Additional Information
(A) Diode-connected Transistors
Diode-connected BJT transistors behave like diodes (which is likely how they got their name) and were commonly used in the design of BJT version of 74xxx logic gates to replace traditional diodes.

Similarly, diode-connected JFET transistors also behave like diodes (see this example). Both BJT and JFET exhibit a forward voltage drop and block reverse-biased current just like diodes.

However, diode-connected MOSFET transistors do not exactly behave like diodes. They do not exhibit true "forward-bias" behavior and instead, conduct current in reverse-biased conditions through their body diodes. Therefore, the term "diode-connected" can be somewhat misleading, although it is widely accepted.
(B) OP Circuit
The circuit configuration shown by the OP is a Drain-Feedback Biasing circuit, which is a self-biasing method to achieve a stable operating point through negative feedback. If the Drain current (\$I_{D}\$) drops, then the Drain voltage (\$V_{D}\$) drops as well, causing the gate-source voltage (\$V_{GS}\$) to increase in magnitude. This drives more Drain current to compensate. Conversely, if \$I_{D}\$ rises, \$V_{D}\$ rises too (because \$V_{D} = I_{D} \times R_{D}\$), causing \$V_{GS}\$ to decrease in magnitude, which reduces the Drain current to stabilize the circuit.
Other Useful Applications
It has several useful applications. Here are three other common usages:
(1) Current Mirror
You can mirror the current on another similar PMOS (it must be a matching PMOS). Here is an interactive demo of the circuit. You can adjust the Drain current of the right-hand side PMOS by varying the supply voltage and/or resistance (by sliding the Voltage and Resistance sliders on the right panel).

Notice that the current on the left leg mirrors the current on the right leg (provided that \$|V_{GS}| > |V_{GS\_thres}|\$).
(2) Voltage Divider
In semiconductor design circuits, you may encounter a voltage divider using a self-biased MOSFET. Here is an interactive simulation of three self-biased N-channel MOSFETs (click on the OPEN CIRCUIT button to simulate). You can adjust the output reference voltages, \$V_{out1}\$ and \$V_{out2}\$, by changing the channel width and length of the MOSFETs.

It is commonly used in semiconductor design to replace polysilicon resistors. Here is an example of a series of self-biased MOSFETs used to generate voltage references in a CMOS version of the 555 IC.

(3) Gate Bias Generator for Bi-Directional Voltage Translator
Below is a 3.3/5V bi-directional voltage translator. The NMOS has a \$V_{GS\_thres}\$ of 1.5V, so the maximum voltage at its Source terminal is \$V_{S} = V_{G} - V_{GS\_thres} = 3.3 - 1.5 = 1.8V\$ when \$V_{D} = 5V\$ (the right-hand switch is open), which is below the desired 3.3V.

To overcome this, we can place a pull-up resistor between the 3.3V power supply and the Source terminal. Another method is to bias the gate voltage (\$V_{G}\$) to a higher voltage, such that \$V_{S}\$ sits at 3.3V when the right-hand switch is open, i.e. \$V_{G} = V_{S} + V_{GS\_thres} = 3.3 + 1.5 = 4.8V\$. We have several ways to achieve this. We could use a voltage divider for biasing, but the Source voltage will drift with temperature. A better approach is to use a matching NMOS in a self-biasing configuration as shown below (in the red box).

With its \$V_{S}\$ fixed at 3.3V, the self-biased NMOS will set an appropriate \$V_{G}\$ such that \$V_{G} = V_{S} + V_{GS\_thres} = 3.3 + 1.5 = 4.8V\$. This gate voltage is shared with the bi-directional NMOS gate, ensuring that you get 3.3V when the latter NMOS's \$V_{D}\$ is greater than 3.3V. The bi-directional NMOS's \$V_{S}\$ is relatively unaffected by temperature changes because the matching NMOS will compensate. Here is the interactive simulation of the gate bias generator. This technique is used in LSF Family of voltage-level translation IC and many others.

An impressive answer, written in depth and richly illustrated... I would like to address some of your claims in my answer.

@Circuit fantasist Thanks for the appraisal. And of course I left out another important usage; that is "Drain-Feedback Biasing configuration as amplifier in common-source mode"

nice work kaosad

I have a question on this part: "They do not exhibit true "forward-bias" behavior and instead, conduct current in reverse-biased conditions through their body diodes." Do the "no bulk" MOSFETs used in this type of circuit, as indicated by the non-standard symbols, actually have (and is it another way of saying) "no body diode"?

The "no bulk" MOSFET symbols are NOT non-standard symbols. They are commonly used in integrated circuit due to its simplicity. "No bulk" does not mean the bulk does not exist; it just means it is connected to some known common point. In places, where the bulk needs to be connected to a specific point, a 4 terminal symbol is used instead.
